# getting defaultArnoldRenderOptions attributes

Tags: maya, pymel, maya-api

I'm trying to write plugin for Maya using pymel. There is a little problem with using default attributes of Arnold renderer (outputfile format).

Code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.imageFormat') #return id of used format, for example png - 32
cmds.getAttr('defaultRenderGlobals.imageFormat') #return constant id=51 if Arnold Renderer set as current renderer
cmds.getAttr('defaultArnoldRenderOptions.?????') #how do the same with arnold options?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have above is not PyMEL. I'll answer with PyMEL since it's what you asked for, and [it's better](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/why_pymel.html) than maya.cmds.

To get a list of all available attributes on a node, use [`listAttr`](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.core.general/pymel.core.general.listAttr.html?highlight=listattr). There are many attributes on **defaultArnoldRenderOptions**, and they are returned unsorted, so you may want to sort or filter the list to make it easier to find.

```
import pymel.core as pm

# all attributes
print pm.listAttr("defaultArnoldRenderOptions")

# print names of attributes sorted, one per line.
print ("\n").join(sorted(pm.listAttr("defaultArnoldRenderOptions")))

#result
...
ignoreSubdivision
ignoreTextures
ignore_list
imageFormat
indirectSampleClamp
indirectSpecularBlur
...
```

There's no outputfileformat, only imageFormat

Get and print the value of the imageFormat attribute

```
print pm.PyNode("defaultArnoldRenderOptions").attr("imageFormat").get()
#result
None
```